# Python read excels and union them

Tags: python

I need to merge several excel files vertically. The files are in the same folder. They have the same columns. However, they don't have a 'Date' column, the date is on excel's name.

for example:

excel 1 named "items_03152021"

has cols:

```
a  b  c
1  2  3
4  5  6
```

excel 2 named "items_03222021"
has cols:

```
a  b  c
2  2  3
3  5  6
```

.
.
.
excel 10 named "items_05172021"
has cols:

```
a  b  c
3  3  3
6  5  6
```

I need to make them like:

```
Date      a   b   c
03152021  1   2   3
03152021  4   5   6
03222021  2   2   3
03222021  3   5   6
.
.
.
05172021  3   3   3
05222021  6   5   6
```

Thank you very much!

JH

Here is the code I tried:

```
all_files = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'c:user\\' ):
    for x in files:
        if '.xlsx' in x:
            all_files.append(root + '\\' + x)
df1 = pd.read_excel([x for x in all_files if '0315' in x][0])
df1.loc[:,'Date'] = '03152021'
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%m%d%Y')

df2 = pd.read_excel([x for x in all_files if '0322' in x][0])
df2.loc[:,'Date'] = '03222021'
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format='%m%d%Y')
.
.
.
df10 = pd.read_excel([x for x in all_files if '0517' in x][0])
df10.loc[:,'Date'] = '05172021'
df10['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df10['Date'], format='%m%d%Y')
```

I just read the excel manually and add the date columns. I am trying to find a way can do them automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Your desired output has all dates the same - are you sure you don't want the dates to reflect the file names? (so the last row would be: 05172021     6     5     6  )

Comment: I edited the question.  the date should same as the excel's name. Thanks.